# adding QWidgets to scrollArea causes them to pile up on top of eachother

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm **somewhat** experienced in python but it's been a looooong time so bear with me on this.

Okay, so I found this really great PyQt code sample where a guy pushes buttons onto a scroll area, which automatically triggers a scrollbar when the content (the buttons) overflow.

So I went and tried to do the very same thing but pushing widgets to the scroll area, this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    _buttons = 0
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("self", "Add Button!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.verticalLayoutScroll = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self._buttons  += 1
        pustButtonName = u"Button {0}".format(self._buttons)

        #pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        #pushButton.setText(pustButtonName)
        muhAlarma = AlarmaWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.verticalLayoutScroll.addWidget(muhAlarma)


class AlarmaWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(AlarmaWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setGeometry(0,0, 30, 30)


        theButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        theButton.setText("It's Friday my dudes.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main = myDialog()

    #main.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    #main.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    #main.showFullScreen()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Upon running this code and pressing the button, buttons will start to appear.
However, the big problem is that instead of filling up the scrollbar area and causing the scrollbar to be enabled, the buttons just end up piling on top of each other, why is that?

PS: uncommenting the commented *pushButton* lines and commenting the *muhAlarma* line will make this sample work again. However I need to push custom widgets, not buttons.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found a solution after almost going crazy for quite a while.
If anyone is having a similar problem, I've got your back!

in

```
AlarmaWidget.__init__
```

set a *minimunHeight* like so:

```
self.setMinimumHeight(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding QWidgets (QPushButton) to scrollArea.
This is the example code for insert  QWidgets (QPushButton) to scrollArea.
Please check this code. Are you expecting this result,
If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
Thanks, Subin

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class myDialog (QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton (self)
        self.button.setObjectName ('button')
        self.button.setText ('Add Button')        

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea (self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable (True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName('scrollArea')

        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName('scrollAreaWidgetContents')
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)   

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout (self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName ('verticalLayout')        

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget (self.scrollArea)        

        self.verticalLayout_scroll = QtGui.QVBoxLayout (self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_scroll.setObjectName ('verticalLayout_scroll')

        self.button.clicked.connect (self.createButtons)

        self.resize(250, 330)


    def createButtons (self) :        
        existsButtonList = []        
        for loop in range (self.verticalLayout_scroll.count ()) :
            if type(self.verticalLayout_scroll.itemAt(loop).widget())==QtGui.QPushButton :
                existsButtonList.append (self.verticalLayout_scroll.itemAt(loop).widget())        

        button_custom   = QtGui.QPushButton (self)
        button_custom.setObjectName ('button%s'% str(len(existsButtonList)+1))
        button_custom.setText ('Add Button - %s'% str(len(existsButtonList)+1))     

        self.verticalLayout_scroll.addWidget(button_custom) 


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = myDialog ()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```